# Notation-use for equations

Tags: notation

Edit: To clarify! This is common notation use in Norway. I wanted to learn whether other conutries used this type of notation.

Is this form of notation use when working with equations common?

A vertical line indicating that the operation will be performed on all terms.

See the two examples (I was unable to format the fractions in the first example, sorry!).

1. If you want to multiply all terms by the same factor:

   x + 2/3 = 4/3 | × 3
2. If you want to divide all terms by the same divisor:

   3(x + 2) = 12  | ÷ 3

I would appreciate if answers include region/nationality. Thanks!

Comment: I do not thin so... but at least use parentheses.

Comment: When you transform one equation into another, it's advisable to explain that transformation with normal text in between them, rather than hoping non-sentential symbols will convey the reasoning linking consecutive equations.

Comment: Well, what is meant by region/nationality? I guess mathematics language is international right now.

Comment: Thanks to all who have replied thus far!
I edited my question to clarify that this is common notation in my country (Norway).
 
There are variations in notation in different regions. For example, in norway the colon is the symbol for division, and a comma is the symbol for decimal points. This is also the case for Ukraine.

Comment: Oh, I learnt something too, about the Norway notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not such notation. You can instead:

If you want to multiply all terms by the same factor:

$$x + 2/3 = 4/3 \\
(x + 2/3) \times 3 = 4/3 \times 3\\
3x + 2 = 4$$
If you want to divide all terms by the same divisor:

$$3(x + 2) = 12\\
3(x + 2) ÷ 3 = 12 ÷ 3\\
x + 2 = 4$$

and add text explanation if you want to be more clear. Do not create your own symbol. It will be confusing.